# Tomcat Virtual Host Not Responding To HTTPS

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, virtualhost

We currently have a tomcat 7 setup that is service the domain A.net and SSL is setup and everything is working fine if you go to https://A.net

We also have a virtual host setup with the following configuration:

```
    <Host name="B.net"  appBase="test_home" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">
          <Context path="" docBase="/mnt/tomcat/test_home/ROOT" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
    </Host>
```

We imported the SSL for B.net into the keystore that is used in the 443 connector.
Everything works well if I go to http://B.net but if I try to access it with https://B.net the requests never come to tomcat. I tried setting up and access log to make sure and I am positive.

Is there any other configuration that needs to be done to support HTTPS on the virtual hosts?

Thanks in advance